# jQuery click event that shows a big image when an image is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have coded in jQuery the following in order to get a clicked image to show in another location but larger. ONLY the jquery code is to be modified. I know I made some mistakes but can't see where after debugging. Also a button checks to see if image was clicked and shows TEXT when criteria is met.

- [Code to be reviewed - had problems pasting all code here](http://pastebin.com/iJSuw7Qf)
- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XAK5N/)

### HTML

```
<div id="question">
    <h2>jQuery Vacation Images</h2>
    <p>What is your first name?
    <input type="text" id="firstname" size="30">
    <span></span>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="vacationimages">
    <p>Click on the Image that best represents the kind of vacation you want</p>
    <p><img src="mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain Vacation"><br /><br /></p>
    <p><img src="desert.jpg" alt="Desert Vacation"><br /><br /></p>
    <p><img src="ocean.jpg" alt="Ocean Vacation"><br /><br /></p>
</div>

<div id="bigimage">
    <img id="currentimage" src="ocean.jpg" alt="ocean vacation" width="300" height="225" border="0">
    <p id="imagedesc"></p>
</div>

<div id="showhidebuttondiv">
    <input id="showhidebutton" type="button" value="Hide Image">
</div>


<div id="submitdiv">
    <input id="submitme" type="button" value="Submit ME">
    <p id="mymessage"></p>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#vacationimages img").click(function()  {
        var changeSrc = $(this).attr("src");
        var changeAlt = $(this).attr("alt");
            $("#currentimg").attr("src", changeSrc); //code to show large clicked image on the right
            $("#imagedesc").text(changeAlt);        //code to show alt under the large image in text
    }); //end of vacation mouse click verification

    $("#submitme").click(function () {
        $("#question span").text("");
        $("#mymessage").text("");
        var myname = $("#firstname").val();
          if (myname == '')  {
            $("#question span").text("Must enter first name");
            return;
          }
        $("#vacationimages img").click(function()  {
            var changeAlt = $(this).attr("alt");
            $(this).data('clicked', true);
            if (myname !== "" || $("#vacationimages img").data('clicked'))
            {
                $("#mymessage").text(myname + " you want a " + changeAlt + " vacation"); //if image clicked and name is set this message will show under the "Submit Me" button
            }
        }) //end of Name Verification for empty field

    })   //end of Submit Me button handler

})  // END OF READY
```

Comment: it will be better if you can copy the code here

Comment: And trim it down to the relevant parts only. I don't think you should expect us to go through *all* of your code and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Jesse All of it is going on! lol. 
@ user2297755 if it's not fixed by the time i take lunch tomorrow, i'll help more!

Comment: HTML is just for reference. The JS code is not that much, I cut the code to only a couple of functions, that probably contain the problem. When debugging, Firefox debugger showed no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XAK5N/3/), here I have updated your jsFiddle with the fixed solution. I have made some changes to your source code, take a look:

```
$("#vacationimages img").click(function () {
    var changeSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    var changeAlt = $(this).attr("alt");
    $("#bigimage img").attr("src", changeSrc); //code to show large clicked image on the right
    $("#imagedesc").text(changeAlt);        //code to show alt under the large image in text
    var changeAlt = $(this).attr("alt");
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    var myname = $("#firstname").val();
    if (myname !== "" || $("#vacationimages img").data('clicked')) {
        $("#mymessage").text(myname + " you want a " + changeAlt + " vacation"); //if image clicked and name is set this message will show under the "Submit Me" button
    }
}); //end of vacation mouse click verification
$("#submitme").click(function () {
    $("#question span").text("");
    $("#mymessage").text("");
    var myname = $("#firstname").val();
    if (myname == '') {
        $("#question span").text("Must enter first name");
        return;
    }
});
```

I hope this will help you more.

Comment: There's only A few changes to the code and some reorganization. When I try to run the code the whole JS code is not working or getting blocked by the new changes. As my first question was "How can I find what the problem is?". I have tried different debugging techniques, like alerts and debugging tools in browsers. Any other suggestions. I have found no problems. Any other code to verify if image was clicked and show larger image? as it is right now still not working.

Comment: Code is working in jsfiddle but for some reason the new code does not work when I try in FIREFOX, CHROME or any other browser. When I take away the new code everything else works fine.

Comment: UPDATE - Got the code working for all verifications the only problem now is showing the BIG image. Here is the code re-organized [link](http://pastebin.com/FEb8FL2H)

Comment: Finally got it working. CSS had "Display: none;" that's why there was no big image. THX to all that helped.

Comment: Accept the answer if you satisfied with my answer.